# Can I apply a script to a specific section (e.g., Results, Conclusions, References etc.) and nowhere else in the document?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I work for a company that provides English editing for scientific papers, and we use macros to speed up the editing process quite significantly. However, we specifically never edit anything in the References/Bibliography, although using macros to automate find & replace operations, things in the References often get changed accidentally. We use Tracked Changes, so I'm trying to write a macro to Reject All Changes in the References.

The very basic macro we have for Reject All Changes is

```
Sub RejectChanges()

    Selection.Range.Revisions.RejectAll

End Sub
```

But this obviously applies to the whole document. The "Selection" part of the code seems to imply to me that you can write code to only apply to different sections of the text. Is something like that possible?

Cheers

Comment: @harrymc `ActiveVBProject.References` refers to the COM libraries loaded in the active VBA project - has nothing to do with Word document references / bibliography.

Comment: References, like footnotes are separate, however, they are linked into the body and if you change it in the body, it can change the linked material, perhaps deleting it. You could perhaps have your code cycle through the tracked changes and accept them if they are references.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It would be meant to run against an existing document where references might have accidentally gotten changed.

```
Sub ScanRevisions()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim eNote As Word.Endnote
    Dim fNote As Word.Footnote
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.Content
    
    For Each eNote In doc.Endnotes
        If eNote.Range.Revisions.Count > 0 Then
            eNote.Range.Revisions.RejectAll
        End If
    Next
    For Each fNote In doc.Footnotes
        If fNote.Range.Revisions.Count > 0 Then
            fNote.Range.Revisions.RejectAll
        End If
    Next
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .Style = doc.Styles("Bibliography").NameLocal
        .Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        While .Execute
            If rng.Revisions.Count > 0 Then
                rng.Revisions.RejectAll
            End If
            rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```